# Converting OpenCV to JavaCV - Need help in function cvHoughLines2()

Tags: java, c++, opencv, image-processing, javacv

I am converting a set of codes written in OpenCV to JavaCV now i am trying to convert the following lines of code into JavaCV :

```
CvSeq lines = null;//Ref 9
lines = cvHoughLines2( Edges,
        storage,
        cv.CV_H,
        1,
        CV_PI/180,
        44,// threshold
        2,
        1 );
```

But i am getting following errors,

1) CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC cannot be resolved
2) CV_PI cannot be resolved

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CV_PI is just a number. You can get in Java with **Math.PI**.
CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC should work (you wrote cv.CV_H ?).

```
CvSeq lines = null;//Ref 9
lines = cvHoughLines2( Edges,
        storage,
        CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC,
        1,
        Math.PI/180,           
        44,// threshold
        2,
        1 );
```